# Como arredondar porcentagem?

Tags: asp, arredondamento

Precisaria da função abaixo em .asp. Não tenho nenhuma noção da linguagem, alguém pode ajudar?

Fiz em JavaScript, segue:

```js
function limparClasse(classe) {
    var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.' + classe);
    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) 
        elementos[i].innerHTML = elementos[i].innerHTML.replace(/,.*%/, "%");
}


limparClasse('vtex-cpShow');
```

```html
<span class="desconto-de vtex-cpSave  vtex-cpShow ">36,00 % OFF</span>
```

Comment: em asp é utilizado o controle $product.ListPriceMinusBestPriceInPercent OFF

Comment: Você está usando um TextBox? Como está atribuindo essa informação?

Comment: O valor vem 30.0 % OFF é gerado pelo sistema

Comment: Que sistema? Você está usando alguma framework? Estou tentando entender o contexto. Pode prover mais detalhes? Está muito vaga sua pergunta.

Comment: É ASP mesmo ou ASP.NET? O problema está relacionado com ASP ou é apenas Javascript?

Comment: É um cms(plataforma vtex), o $product.ListPriceMinusBestPriceInPercent seria um controle. Este controle gera a porcentagem dentro do <span> com duas casas decimais, precisaria arredondar.

Comment: bigown seria  ASP.NET. O problema está na verdade com o javascript, estou usando um infinite scroll(plugin) de produtos mas não consigo incluir a função que citei quando é carregado novos produtos. Por isso estou tentando arredondar diretamente pelo asp.net, se for possível.

Comment: De onde vêm as informações? É necessário o código completo, ou se fosse fornecido apenas a maneira de substituir uma string por outra, ajudaria?

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver por incrível que pareça por CSS(rs) width e overflow:hidden.

Comment: @lucasinverso na verdade deste jeito você resolveu na sua tela e no seu browser. essa solução de esconder pedaço de string vai dar problema, dependendo do tamanho dos dígitos, do browser envolvido e mais uma série de fatores. Sugestão: clique em "editar" embaixo da pergunta, explique direitinho o resultado que você quer, com exemplos (não só de código), para que possamos votar para reabrir a questão, e alguém possa dar uma resposta de verdade.

Answer (score 2):

Calcule normalmente a porcentagem em ASP e utilize a função `Round` para arredondar.

> Exemplo 1

```
<%

    response.write(Round(24.13278) & "<br />")
    response.write(Round(24.75122))

%>
```

Resultado:

```
24
25
```

> Exemplo 2

Arredondamento, mantendo 2 casas decimais:

```
<%

    response.write(Round(24.13278,2))

%>
```

Resultado:

```
24.13
```

[VBScript Round Function](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_round.asp)